# Website not loading properly in Chome mobile, but loads fine in Firefox mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a website for a local social group/cafe, my first website, did it for free for the practice.  Anyway, when I look at the site in Chrome on Android, the loading bar gets stuck at a quarter of the way, and the page doesn't load properly.  It loads everything except the logo in the nav bar.  When I try the same site in Firefox on Android, it loads quickly and completely.  It also works fine in all desktop browsers, it's just Chrome on Android that's the problem.
The page in question is http://belfastsolidarity.org/library - any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: It work fine on my chrome on android, try to use inspect mode to see if there have any errors.

Comment: The website loads fine in Chrome for Android. This problem might happen in your device in Chrome because of cache issue or memory issue. The problem is purely in your device. What you can do: Clear Chrome data from `Settings > Apps > Chrome`. Disable Data Saver option in Chrome browser. If nothing works, uninstall and re-install the app.

Comment: When I inspect your website I get this error: \Failed to parse SourceMap: http://belfastsolidarity.org/css/bootstrap.min.css.map